# How do I use for loop?

Tags: bash

```
#/bin/bash
file='abc1'
ln -s $file.grd GGG.grd
TTT >file-out.txt

file='abc2'
ln -s $file.grd GGG.grd
TTT >file-out.txt
```

In this case, how can I modify the code?

Comment: btw sounds like a bash question, why tag as vim?

Comment: in vim you can write `for loop`, but your question is not clear. what do you want to do?  why vim?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `TTT >$file-out.txt` rather than `TTT >file-out.txt`? Also, I've removed "in vim" from the title, since it didn't seem relevant.

Comment: Keith Thompson. You are right. It should be TTT >$file-out.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
#/bin/bash
for n in 1 2 3
do
  file="abc$n"
  ln -s $file.grd GGG.grd
  TTT >file-out.txt
done
```

---

If you print the variable $file in the loop then it is easy to see if it becomes abc1..3

```
#/bin/bash
for n in 1 2 3
do
        file="abc$n"
        echo $file
done
```

And this prints:

```
abc1
abc2
abc3
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried your suggestion but it read abc$n instead of abc1, abc2. Is there other way?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `TTT >$file.out.txt`? (The error is copied from the question; I'll comment there as well.)

Comment: @user3642693, you would get `abc$n` if you use `file='abc$n'`. I don't see why you will get `abc$n` if you use `file="abc$n"`.

Comment: @user3642693 I get abc1 abc2 abc3 with my mini example, do you get the same result?

Comment: FYI: You can use `for n in {1..3}` which will save typing when moving to larger numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. It worked when I changed 'abc$n' to "abc$n"!!